# open browser with own port address?

Tags: apache, wamp

I am new to WAMP. I changed its port from 80 to 2020 but when I load "localhost" in the browser, it redirects to browser with "localhost" but I want "localhost:2020". How do I do this?

Comment: `when I start localhost` Huh?

Comment: after click on the wamp icon> localhost..

Comment: HTTP is served on port 80 by default. Unless WAMP has a setting to control how the browser is launched and what URL it goes to; you're stuck with `localhost:80`

Comment: then what should be chane in wamp setting (wampmanager.ini file)?

Comment: @RamMahipale: What WAMP icon?  Is that a shortcut? If so, change it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide: http://abishekravi.blogspot.com/2010/01/tweaking-wamp-manager-configuration.html

It shows three locations in wampmanager.ini where you need to change localhost to localhost:2020 (why aren't you using 8080?) and two more in wampmanager.tpl.